# Can a pointer be used to traverse an array of chars?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, while-loop

Can I use char* bufferpntr to traverse an array that is pointed to by char* buffer?

example:

```
delete [] bufferpntr;
bufferpntr = nullptr;
buffer = nullptr;
buffer =  new char [MAX];
bufferpntr = buffer;

cout << "How many data entries:\t";
cin.getline(buffer, MAX, '\n');


 while (*bufferpntr != '\0')
     cout << setw(2) << bufferpntr++;
```

however, when I compile the code and run it, i crashes right after printing the first index.

Comment: They *can*, but this looks very prone to error.

Comment: The crash is probably not related to the exact code you chose to show us. http://sscce.org

Comment: Is MAX 1 by any chance?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I don't think `MAX` being `1` would cause a crash there

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. In C++ pointers are bidirectional iterators and can be used to iterate over a valid buffer. There are also more idiomatic ways of approaching this problem that eliminate the necessity of managing the memory for the string buffer yourself. In your case you would be better of using `std::string` and `std::getline`. This way you can read an input line regardless of it's size (as long as it fits in available memory of course) and not worry about allocating and releasing resources.

The following example matches your requirements to read a line from `std::cin` and output each character of the string.

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string inputLine;

    std::getline(std::cin, inputLine);
    const char *ptr = inputLine.c_str();
    while(*ptr)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << *ptr++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess: the delete statement causes the crash but it only becomes apparent later. Try without the delete and show us a complete program that crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I got it figured out in the context of my project. I decided to take the input as a char array, and it worked out

Comment: I'm sure it works, and generations of C programmers have written good software using `char*` arrays. BUT: It's much more likely to make errors than with `std::string` and/or `std::vector`, because you have to make sure by yourself not to run into buffer overflows -- btw one of the most common reasons for software vulnerabilities. It may not matter in a small test program, but for larger C++ projects you should by all means avoid "naked" pointers, `char*` and other C-style arrays.